# Why do we feel weightless while free fall but not while hanging with a string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

So why do we feel weighted by hanging on a string as their is  no normal force acting on the object only tension force on the string not on object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the string case, the tension of the string is stopping you from falling, but the part of you attached to the string still needs to exert force on the rest of you to stop the rest of you from falling as well.

In the case of free-fall, no part of your body has more force acting on it than any other part, meaning that you feel weightless.

Comment: "*In the case of free-fall, no part of your body has more force acting on it than any other part, meaning that you feel weightless.*" In other words, your body (or any other physical object for that matter) can only detect forces relative to other parts of itself through strain/deformation.